# awk to get IP info

Tags: awk, gawk

I was going to write a bash script to pull out info I wanted from ifconfig -a

but then I saw this bash one liner:

```
/sbin/ifconfig | awk -v RS="\n\n" '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "inet" && $(i+1) ~   /^addr:/) address = substr($(i+1), 6); if (address != "127.0.0.1") printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, address }'
```

Which produces output like:

```
eth1    10.91.5.189
eth2    10.101.3.96
```

I would like to strip more info out than this though... so I would like:

```
ethX MAC-add IP Bcast Mask
```

... how can I alter the above one liner to get the output I am after?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976928/parsing-data-from-ifconfig-with-awk-or-sed

Comment: @jaypal he wants to have the output in one line. check the code he referenced, it prints things in single line.

Comment: Take a look at http://commandlinefu.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version based on Kents verson:

```
ifconfig -a|awk -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="HWaddr") mac=$(i+1)
        else if($i~/addr:[0-9]/) {split($i,a,":");ip=a[2]}
        else if($i~/Mask/) {split($i,a,":");mask=a[2]}}
    if(ip!="127.0.0.1")print $1,mac,ip,bcast,mask}'
eth0 00:18:71:6a:f0:45 192.168.1.30 255.255.255.0
```

I have skipped the Broad Cast address, since its always the last IP in the segment and normally not needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this, should work:

```
 ifconfig -a|awk -v RS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i=="inet")ip=$(i+1);
        else if($i=="broadcast")bcast=$(i+1);
        else if($i=="ether")mac=$(i+1);
        else if($i=="netmask")mask=$(i+1)}
        if(ip!="127.0.0.1")print $1,mac,ip,bcast,mask}'
```

Comment: The output of `ifconfig` is system dependent so this might require a bit of tweaking.

Comment: eg eth1 addr:192.168.1.1

Comment: @mbbxedh2 I thought you would get the idea if you read my codes.

Comment: Thanks Kent... I realised yours was for ifconfig output on a mac- threw me off a bit but with morning eyes I caught on... thanks again

Comment: @mbbxedh2 I don't have mac. my ifconfig is from: `net-tools 2.10-alpha`